# Inicio de sesión en android studio no funciona correctamente debido a que el response nunca está vacio

Tags: php, mysql, android, kotlin, login

Estoy haciendo un inicio de sesión para mi aplicación en android studio utilizando kotlin. El caso es que no importa lo que introduces, da igual que pongas un usurario y la contraseña correspondiente que se encuentra en mysql. Pasa a la siguiente pantalla como si de verdad hubieses introducido correctamente los datos. El logcat no me da ningún error, y en el evenlog tampoco, por lo creo que el fallo está en que hay un if en el que si el response no está vacío te deja pasar a la otra pantalla, y si está vacio te dice que el usuario o la contraseña son incorrectas. ¿Verdaderamente ese el problema de que pase a la otra pantalla sin importar lo  que introduzcas? ¿Cómo se puede hacer para que si no se introducen bien el nombre de usuario o la contraseña el response este vacío? ¿Qué debería modificar de mi código? No se como arreglar el problema y agradezco cualquier ayuda. Muchas gracias.
Este es el codigo php:

```
<?php
  require 'database.php';
if(!empty($_POST['nombre']) && !empty($_POST['password'])){
    $records = $conn->prepare('SELECT id, email, password, nombre FROM usuarios WHERE nombre = :nombre');
    $records->bindParam(':nombre', $_POST['nombre']);
    $records->execute();
    $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $message ='';
    if (count($results)>0 && password_verify($_POST['password'], $results['password'])){
      echo json_encode($results,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }
};
?>
```

Y este es el codigo de android studio (kotlin):

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
import java.util.HashMap

class Login : AppCompatActivity() {
    var nombreusuariologin: EditText? = null
    var contraseñalogin: EditText? = null
    var enviarlogin: Button? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

        nombreusuariologin = findViewById(R.id.nombreusuario)
        contraseñalogin = findViewById(R.id.contraseña)
        enviarlogin = findViewById(R.id.enviarlogin)
        enviarlogin!!.setOnClickListener { validarUsuario("http://192.168.1.47/Registro/loginapp.php") }
    }
    private fun validarUsuario(URL: String) {
        val stringRequest: StringRequest = object : StringRequest(
            Method.POST,
            URL,
            Response.Listener { response ->
                if (!response.isEmpty()) {
                    if(response != null && !response.isEmpty()){
                        val intent = Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java)
                        startActivity(intent)
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this@Login,
                        "Usuario o contraseña incorrecto",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            },
            Response.ErrorListener { error ->
                Toast.makeText(
                    this@Login,
                    error.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }) {
            @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
            override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
                val parametros: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()
                parametros.put("nombre",nombreusuariologin?.text.toString())
                parametros.put("password",contraseñalogin?.text.toString())
                return parametros
            }
        }
        val requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!response.isEmpty()) {
                    if(response != null && !response.isEmpty()){
                        val intent = Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java)
                        startActivity(intent)
                    }
                }
```

Si se pasa siempre al siguiente intent significa que estos dias if se evalúan a true (date cuenta que el primero te sobra ya que esa condición se repite en el segundo). En cualquier caso, esto quiere decir que response nunca es nulo y nunca viene vacío, pongas bien o mal el usuario y contraseña. Conforme esta planteado tu código tu problema está en el código PHP pues en caso de introducir mal las credenciales la respuesta tendría que venir vacía para que !response.isEmpty() no se cumpla y pasa al bloque de else renderizando el Toast. Para ver esto de forma gráfica, añade un print antes de los if y verás que response siempre tiene contenido y, por eso, siempre pasa a la siguiente Activity.

Lo que yo haría sería añadir un bloque else al código PHP y añadir a $result un campo para controlar esto. Por ejemplo:

```
if (count($results)>0 && password_verify($_POST['password'], $results['password'])){
      $results['success'] = True;
      echo json_encode($results,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }
else {
      $results['success'] = False;
      echo json_encode($results,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}
```

Y luego en tu código Kotlin recuperas esa variable y la evaluas:

```
if(response != null && response.success){
                        val intent = Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java)
                        startActivity(intent)
                    }
```

Esto es un esqueleto, creo que response.success no se lo va a tragar pero ya ves la idea que has de seguir: añadir una variable en tu PHP para manejar el caso de éxito o fallido y luego recuperarlo en la app android porque la comprobación de si la respuesta viene vacía o no, es una pésima idea.

Te recomiendo que le eches un ojo a esta librería para hacer peticiones http que es realmente potente, si quieres ser developer android debes conocerla obligatoriamente. Tienes mucha info sobre Retrofit en la red :)

https://square.github.io/retrofit/

https://cursokotlin.com/tutorial-retrofit-2-en-kotlin-con-corrutinas-consumiendo-api-capitulo-20-v2/

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, pero si se usa Volley como indica la pregunta cómo se  podría corregir el problema?, te sugerimos revisar [answer], revisa lo referente a los enlaces , saludos..

Comment: @jopimi Como soluciono que me aparezca unresolve reference en success?

Comment: @Elenasys Como soluciono que me aparezca unresolve reference en success?

Comment: Desconozco por completo PHP. Qué tipo de dato es result? No sé si es una lista o un objeto... De todas maneras no tienes porque devolver results tu puedes decidir que devolver. Para un login con devolver un json que contenga un true o false es suficiente, pero ya depende de tus necesidades.  Dime que tipo de dato es $result y averiguo como puedes manipularlo.